# Get clicked <li> item as child inside <ul> <li> parent with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create nested menu items with React.
I want to create Menu component like this:

```
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item-1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent Item 2</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <ul class="dropdown-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Item2.1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I created `MenuItem` component for `li`.If user set `parent` prop is true then user should create sub `MenuItems` inside of `MenuItem` like in below:

```
<Menu>
 <MenuItem text="Item-1">
 <MenuItem text="Parent Item 2" parent>
   <MenuItem text="Item2.1">
 </MenuItem>
<MenuItem text="Item3">
</Menu>
```

I want to show selected menu item when clicked but if  parent item is exist it shows only parent item text.It couldn't get child menu item text.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because the event is bubbling to the parent.
If that is the cause, using `evt.stopPropagation()` in click handler would prevent the issue.

I tried this in codesandbox to demo the similar situation.

That the list only change the background color when it is click, and prevent the change of parent list.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-hooks-r5j3g?fontsize=14

Here is a article about event bubbling:

https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#stopping-bubbling